# Correlation between sequential binary choices

Tags: autocorrelation, binary-data, autoregressive

I have an experiment in which subjects perform a binary choice for each question. I want to explore the effect of n-1 choice on the nth choice. I think it has something to do with autocorrelation but I am really not familiar with this. I know quite good SPSS and can handle R.